# Can Adwords Advertisers see which Adsense Publishers send them traffic?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, analytics, google-ads

I have a blog with adsense on it. An advertisement I see a lot from my adsense is a Telus phone banner.

If people click this Telus banner ad and go to Telus website, will Telus be able to see where these people came from? For example, can they see my blog url on their google-analytic Referrals section (assuming they have one) ??

Answer (score 1):

The `HTTP_REFERER` header for AdSense ads used to be from a doubleclick.net domain and the real URL needed to be extracted from it. However, I've just checked and it now shows up as the page where the ad was placed (as it should).

It's always been possible to see a list of AdSense referrers via a report in the main AdWords interface but some of them just show up in a category of 'other' domains so isn't complete.

However, your question led me to investigate Google Analytics further and I can see that there is now a report called 'Placements' in the 'Traffic Sources > AdWords' menu that lists all of the referral domains and URL's.

So the short answer to your question is yes!